# Turn Login Script into Function

Tags: python-3.x

I am having a little trouble completing this, I recently wrote this login script, but I am now tasked with turning it into a function. The goal is for the function to accept the username and password, it should return true. If incorrect, it's supposed to prompt the user up to 4 more times for their password locking them out after 5 attempts.

```
 def authenticateuser(username, password):
     username = "homerjsimpson"
     password = "marge"

 def main():

     username = ""
     password = ""

     loggedin = False
     wrongcount = 0


 while loggedin == False and wrongcount < 5:
         username = input("Please enter username: ")
         password = input("Please enter password: ")
     if password == thepassword and username == theusername:
         loggedin = True
     else:
         print("Authentication Failed")
         wrongcount = wrongcount + 1
         loggedin = False

 if(loggedin == True):
     print("Welcome to the program!")
 else:
     print("Locked Out")

 main()
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: You have an error in your logic because of improper indentation. The program is stuck in your while loop.

Comment: Its more of a logic error im having rather than a specific error, my goal is to create a function called "autheticateuser" and call that to run the script. If that makes sense. I've been messing with the code more but can't find the right spot for everything. I added the changes I made to the code, not sure if I actually need username = " " and password = " " in the beginning of the main() or not. Also I can't get the script to recognize Loggedin = False

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def authenticateuser(theusername, thepassword):
    if theusername == "homerjsimpson" and thepassword == "marge":
        return (True)
    else:
        return (False)


def main():

    username = ""
    password = ""   

loggedin = False
wrongcount = 0


while loggedin == False and wrongcount < 5:
    username = input("Please enter username: ")
    password = input("Please enter password: ")
    if authenticateuser(username, password):
        loggedin = True
    else:
        print("Authentication Failed")
        wrongcount = wrongcount + 1
        loggedin = False

if(loggedin == True):
    print("Welcome to the program!")
else:
    print("Locked Out")

main()
```